# Boost (BGL): How do dis-obfuscate my errors?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-graph

I seem to recall reading about a way to 'reduce' the size of template spew in compiler errors associated with the boost libraries. My recollection is that it gives the template parameters nicer names than the compiler default naming (which is quite horrid).

Is this real, or did I dream about it? I've been trying to find where I read this but I can't seem to locate anything - is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard this works well.
http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html

It is a perl script that parses the error messages a generates more readable versions

Comment: This looks interesting, but I'm holding out for my recollection of an argument/command/trick that is a part of boost and specific to their absurdly templated functions (sometimes 7 template parameters).

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing. But if it exists, I'd like to know about it too! :-)

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing either. But STLfilt works quite well and you may customize it to your needs, once you understand a bit how the perl script works. Note that, using the C part of STLfilt, you may create your own reinterpreter if you want.

Comment: I found what I was thinking of. It's a compiler extension that was mentioned in the boost forums, especially made for boost.

Answer (score 2):

Ladies and Gentlemen [this](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2002/03/27321.php) GCC extension is exactly what I was thinking of ...

Comment: That looks like a proposal. Was it ever implemented. I did a little searching and haven't found it.